# CSS of Stack Overflow invalid as per W3C?

Tags: discussion, design

I have recently installed the Firefox debugging toolbar and just for fun was validating the CSS of a question on Stack Overflow and amazingly found [100+ errors on it](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css3&warning=0&uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F92082%2Fadd-a-column-with-a-default-value-to-an-existing-table-in-sql-server%3Frq%3D1). Ok! There can be errors, but isn't it too much and bit ironic for Stack Overflow?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes you have to break the rules to look beautiful

Comment: Eh, there *are* some value errors in there that should definitely be corrected. E.g. `unset` is not a valid value for top, right, bottom, left. And there are some extraneous `\000009`s attached to various values.

Comment: The `\000009` is a [hack for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8004962/559745).

Comment: I guess the W3C standards are all great. All we need is a 100% standards compliant browser ...

Comment: [Facebook have 15 errors](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en)

Comment: @SagarV only 15?  That's surprising...

Comment: @silencedmessage That's just the homepage, which is nothing more than a login screen.  I'm sure on a person's profile or feed there'd be a lot more.

Answer (score 12):

The Jigsaw validator is known to be severely outdated with [numerous bugs even in the checks that it *does* implement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A106224+%5Bcss%5D+validator+bug). Many of the features used are from future standards which the Jigsaw validator doesn't make a concerted effort to support.

Don't worry about it.

Comment: is there a more modern validator?

Comment: @Moshe: Sadly, no. The only way I can reliably validate my own CSS is by cross-referencing with the specs, and asking the WG when in doubt - and that's only because I'm familiar enough with the specs to do so. Most others don't have much of an alternative...

Comment: "I am my own CSS validator." -BoltClock :-p

Comment: Pretty much, @Cody. And as shown in my link I am happy to, er, avail my validation services to others for free, provided they've at least run their code through *some* other service first.